# How do I use a txt file inside of a jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text

I want to use a txt file in a jar file.

I am using eclipse.

I have the txt file in a folder called "resources" inside of my project folder.

Here is the code that I am trying to use to get the txt file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/list of names.txt"));
```

This works when running the code in eclipse, but it doesn't work after I export it as a .jar file and run it.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to get an `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/list of names.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```